# How to search two MySql tables using a join with conditions

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

Customers: ID, Email, Firstname, Lastname, IsSubscribed, SiteID
Payments: CustomerID, PayStatus

I want to search all customers, who have elected to be on my mailing list, from a particular site and who have made a payment.

**This is what I have got:**

```
SELECT Email, Firstname, Lastname FROM Customers t1 
WHERE t1.IsSubscribed='1' 
AND t1.SiteID=’414’ 
INNER JOIN Payments t2 
ON t1.ID = t2.CustomerID
WHERE PayStatus=1;
```

I have been using ORM for a number of years now and I have completely forgotten how to use MySQL properly...

Any guidance on how to do this correctly would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can't have two where clauses in a query. But you can put all the conditions into one (at the end) easily enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this query:

```
SELECT Email, Firstname, Lastname FROM Customers t1
INNER JOIN Payments t2 
ON t1.ID = t2.CustomerID 
WHERE t1.IsSubscribed='1' 
AND t1.SiteID=’414’    
AND t2.PayStatus=1;
```

Comment: Argh - yes I should have had the innner join right at the start... thanks!